# how to get the highest value for each category using java

Tags: java, xml

I have an XML string as input like below. For each question, there are multiple choices. How can I get the highest score for each question?

Thank you.

```
<root>
 <Q>
 <QID>1</QID>
 <Ans>
  <Score>1</Score>
  <Choice>Choice 1</Choice>
 </Ans>
 <Ans>
  <Score>2</Score>
  <Choice>Choice 2</Choice>
 </Ans>
 <Ans>
  <Score>3</Score>
  <Choice>Choice 3</Choice>
 </Ans>
 </Q>
 <Q>
 <QID>2</QID>
 <Ans>
  <Score>10</Score>
  <Choice>Choice A</Choice>
 </Ans>
 <Ans>
  <Score>20</Score>
  <Choice>Choice B</Choice>
 </Ans>
 <Ans>
  <Score>30</Score>
  <Choice>Choice C</Choice>
 </Ans>   
 </Q>
</root>
```

Comment: Do you have any code snippet to show? what have you tried so far? There is multiple ways of achieving your task. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @yogidilip Yes. I tried below but code returns the highest score of the entire xml. 
nlElement1 = xPath.evaluate("//" + "QID", doc.getDocumentElement(), javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants.NODESET);
nlElement2 = xPath.evaluate("//" + "Score", doc.getDocumentElement(), javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants.NODESET);
for (int i = 0; i < nlElement1.getLength(); i++)
{
double maxScore = 0.00;
for (int j = 0; j < nlElement2.getLength(); j++) 
{
if (Double.parseDouble(nlElement2.item(j).getTextContent()) >= maxScore)
{
maxScore = Double.parseDouble(nlElement2.item(j).getTextContent());
}
}
}

Comment: @Michael You should add this code to your original question. Look up how to format the code properly in markdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to calculate the highest score per question, you can use a map: The key is question ID and the value is the question highest score:

```
Map<Integer, Double> scoreMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Then you simply need to do a double iterations, where the outer one is for questions, and the inner one for choices and scores:

```
Map<Integer, Double> scoreMap = new HashMap<>();
XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
NodeList questions = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("/root/Q", document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
for (int i = 0; i < questions.getLength(); i++) {
  Node question = questions.item(i);
  int questionId = Integer.parseInt(xpath.evaluate("QID", question));
  System.out.println("question: " + questionId);
  NodeList answers = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("Ans/Score", question, XPathConstants.NODESET);
  double maxScore = 0;
  for (int j = 0; j < answers.getLength(); j++) {
    System.out.println("score: " + answers.item(j).getTextContent());
    double score = Double.parseDouble(answers.item(i).getTextContent());
    maxScore = Math.max(score, maxScore);
  }
  scoreMap.put(questionId, maxScore);
}
scoreMap.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + ": " + v));
```

It prints:

```
question: 1
score: 1
score: 2
score: 3
question: 2
score: 10
score: 20
score: 30
1: 1.0
2: 20.0
```

Comment: Thank you. It really helps. I also found a similar way to use DOM parser to get the node of <Ans> and then use for loop to get the highest score. But your way is better than mine. Thanks.